# JavaFX Screen size?

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I'm using a [PiTFT](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2097) on my pi and running a JavaFX program.  I got the output going to the PiTFT by running [fbcp](https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp) in the background.
I had to set `disable_overscan=1` in /boot/config.txt to get it to show the whole image.  That all works fine now.

My problem is that the touch screen calibration doesn't seem to effect JavaFX apps.  The X and Y axis are swapped.  Does anybody know how to calibrate the touch screen for JavaFX apps?

I don't know if this is a problem with the touchscreen driver for the PiTFT or a JavaFX configuration problem, so I'm going to post the same question to the [adafruit forums](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=64095) and if I get an answer in one place, I'll copy it to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've struggled with the same problem today, and I managed to figure it out.

The PiTFT is by default a portrait display with a resolution of 240x320. The driver conf is originally made to rotate the display. The touchscreen setting for X are aware of that and have the rotate option set accordingly. And yes, this will not affect JavaFX since it doesn't run in X.

What I did:

in /boot/config.txt

```
disable_overscan=1
framebuffer_width=480
framebuffer_height=640
#set specific CVT mode
hdmi_cvt 480 640 60 1 0 0 0
#set CVT as default
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

With this, the main display resolution is set to 480x640, and overscan is disabled.

Next, in /etc/modprobe.d/adafruit.conf, change the rotate option to be 0.

Save everything and reboot. Then fbcp & java Main, and it should be working OK.

Btw, be aware that I used the pre-built raspbian image from adafruit.

Comment: This seems like it will work.  Of course now my program is displayed with a 90 degree rotation, but I should be able to rotate the whole thing to make it fit.  I can't verify that the touch screen is correct just yet. My program only has one menu icon at startup and it's currently off the screen :-)

Comment: Confirmed!  Thanks!  Now if I could just get JavaFX to display directly to fb1 instead of having to use fbcp to copy fb1 to fb0.  It works, but there's a kworker process using 44% of the CPU the entire time that fbcp is running. It looks like OpenJDK has more display options if I could get it to build.  But that will have to be another topic.